# two git branches define functions at the end of a file; how can I prevent git from trying to combine them (which creates a conflict)?

Tags: git

Let's say I have a file hello.php, which defines function a().

Now, a branch "b" defines function b() at the end of the file hello.php.

Meanwhile, further development occurs on the branch master at the end of hello.php: function c() is defined.

At this point I have two branches:

- master which defines functions a() and c()
- branch b which defines functions a() and b()

Now, when I'm in master and I want to merge b into it, git attempts to combine functions b() and c() and creates a bunch of conflicts (this is especially hard to untangle for long functions). In this case, I don't want them to be combined at all and, furthermore, it is really not important if c() is defined before b(), or b() before c().

Is there any way to tell git that, when modifications are made at the end of a file, they should always be placed at the end, regardless of what comes before, so that merging master in branch b would yield function a(), function b(), function c(); and merging branch b into master would yield function a(), function c(), function b().

Thanks!

Albert

Answer (score 2):

No. This is the kind of scenario that you just have to resolve the conflict manually.

You can, however, try turning on the 3-way conflict display, which could make things easier to resolve:

```
$ git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found diff3 and merge tools a bit too complex for me. Rather, I use the following technique: adding a placeholder at the end of files. For example, in the master branch, a php file might end with:

```
...
/* new code after this line */
/* new code before this line */
```

Now, two new branches might each add some new code between these lines. When each new branch is actually merged into master, I will start by merging my new branch into master, and then move the `/* new code after this line */` line to the end of the file, above the last line.

Then, I can merge my other branch which also defined some new code, and so on.

The result is that git does not attempt to combine new code together, but rather puts new code cleanly at the end of files in the order in which the branches were merged.

Answer (score 0):

When you pull one branch into another you can select a merge tool and select which branch pieces of code should be used.

I'd do:

```
Git checkout master
Git pull origin branch_b
Git mergetool
```

This should allow you to choose 'left' or 'right' or both to determine which code to use.

If you've got this far and are still having issues I'll update accordingly.